# USB 2.0 FS device over USB C with both power directions

Tags: usb, usb-device, usb-c, usb-pd, usb-2

I'm designing a battery-powered device with the following requirements:

- rq1: (a) Charge the device's battery over a USB C receptacle, or (b) provide power over the same receptacle. Both directions are restricted to 5 V. Switching should be done via the device MCU's firmware.
- rq2: Allow USB data transfer where the device is a full-speed USB 2.0 function.
- rq3: Needs not to comply with the USB standard (it's a one-off private project), but should function with a variety of USB C chargers and USB C power sinks.

From previous projects, I gathered some experience with the older USB standards. However, the whole power handling (i.e., either sourcing or sinking current) as well as USB C and USB PD are quite new to me. For the former, I'm planning to use TI's BQ25890 IC, which should have me covered (please feel free to veto, if there's an obvious issue).

The latter is the bigger of my concerns. From what I've researched (e.g., 1, 2), satisfying rq2 while the device is supplying power requires actually implementing the USB PD protocol. Let's, therefore, restrict rq2 to the power sink case.

Here is a rough schematic of what I've come up with so far:

[image: Schematic Showing Solution Sketch]

The MCU connects to USB_D{+,-}, PD_{SOURCE,SINK}, and FROM_PHY. BQ25890 handles VBUS.

My concrete questions are:

1. Will I be able to avoid implementing USB PD with this approach?
2. Are the CC lines configured correctly for what I'm trying to achieve (sourcing 1.5A is fine). Further, how crucial is timing when changing between source and sink?
3. Is the pull-up resistor on D+ still necessary? It's built into the nrf52840 I'm planning to use.
4. Making the approach backward-compatible to charging USB B devices should be as easy as plugging in a USB C <-> USB B adapter cable and switching to PD_SOURCE, right?
5. A little off topic: is connecting the shield via a ferrite bead sufficient to avoid ESD issues when (un-)plugging the cable?

Sorry if this is all a bit mixed up. The newer USB practices are quite overwhelming for me and similar questions received answers, that sometimes seem to contradict each other.

(1) [Can you do type-C USB DRP, UFP data, sourcing device with CC controller only?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/604629/can-you-do-type-c-usb-drp-ufp-data-sourcing-device-with-cc-controller-only)

(2) [USB DRP Reference Design (Dynamic USB-C sink/source + USB 2.0 data)](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/580980/usb-drp-reference-design-dynamic-usb-c-sink-source-usb-2-0-data)

Comment: The body diodes in Q2B and Q3B are going to scupper this approach.

Comment: Besides all the problems, will this device need to be a host and sink, or always host or always sink, but negotiate power in or out?

Comment: Also, what is VBUS connected to in your design? You will need to implement switching of power to this pin when acting as a source.

Comment: Thanks you two. @Justme: There was exactly one issue mentioned before your comment. Could you please elaborate "what all the problems" means? Aside from that, the terms are not completely clear to me. As far as I'm aware, it should be either an UFP (data) + sink (power), or a source (power) without data.

Comment: @Finbarr: You're right, I didn't think about the body diodes. I assume there's dedicated chips for that? VBUS is connected to the BQ25890 and therefore capable of performing the power switch. That's why I' concerned with the transition time / sequence.

Comment: The BQ25890 is just a battery charger IC. I don't think it has connections for things like the CC lines on a USB-C port or full power path management.

Comment: As per datasheet, the BQ25890 is a switching-mode battery charger, capable of reversing the power direction in order to supply VBUS from battery (OTG mode). It can actually interface the D+/D- lines for legacy USB OTG mode, hence the questions how to deal with a USB C situation.

Comment: Does the device needs to support dead battery mode? (meaning it should charge via USB when the battery is fully flat and the microcontroller is not working) This feature makes circuit design way more tricky without a dedicated controller chip

Comment: I'd call that a bonus, @Ferrybig: The microcontroller should shut down the vast majority of the current consumption using the BQ25890's transportation mode (disconnects battery from load) at around 3.1V or 3.2V, while the low-voltage cutoff will be at 2.9V. However, what is the issue with the dead battery handling? Again the Rd resistors on the CC lines?

Comment: Supporting dead battery mode is difficulty. The issue is chicken and egg problem. You would need power to enable the mosfets for the 5.1k resistor, but you only receive power once you enable the 5.1k resistors. To support dead battery mode, you would need. One way to do this is using ultra low logic mosfets and connecting them like the following: https://community.infineon.com/t5/Knowledge-Base-Articles/Dead-battery-charging-implementation-in-CCG1-solutions/ta-p/259059